# Struts 1.3 : Difference between name and attribute attributes in action tag within StrutsConfig.xml?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts, struts-1

What is the difference between ***name*** and ***attribute*** attributes in action tag within StrutsConfig.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `name` is the name of the form bean (an `ActionForm` of some sort).
- `attribute` is the name of the form bean in the session or request if it's *different* than the name.

Comment: why should they be different ? we could use only the "name" attribute in form-bean tag to identify the form bean, right ?

Comment: @mounaim In general, they *shouldn't* be different, but that's not the point--they *may* be different, and this is the mechanism that allows that.