# In struts-config.xml, an action has an "attribute" attribute in it. What's it do?

Tags: struts-1, struts-config

In our web app's struts-config.xml file, there are a bunch of `<action>`s defined, and they have both a `name` and an `attribute` attribute on most of them, with the form name in both. For example:

```
<action
    attribute="LoginForm"  <-- this line
    name="LoginForm"
    path="/welcome"
    type="com.foo.presentation.action.LandingActionPre">
    <forward name="SUCCESS" path="landing.welcome" />
    <forward name="ALREADY_LOGGED_IN" path="/landing.do?m=getLandingPage" redirect="true"/>
</action>
```

What does the `attribute` attribute do? Or is it not used and is present here by mistake?

This app has been around for ~10 years, and has seen over 40 programmers touch the code base during that time. So it's possible that one added it to a few actions and every one else copied and pasted it throughout the rest of the app not knowing any better.

Comment: I have never heard of the **attribute** attribute. Does it make a difference if you omit it?

Comment: Well, I have one `<action>` that has a different form name in `attribute` vs `name`, and the `name` one is used. So I guess not. [edit:] And if I remove it, nothing seems to happen, good or bad.

Comment: So it's probably as you said that every one just copied and pasted it to be on the safe side...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27424449/438992 and the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Struts 1 doc type definition](http://fossies.org/linux/xplanner/xplanner/war/WEB-INF/struts-config_1_1.dtd#l_357), it is used as a sort of alias for the ActionForm.

If it's the same as `name`, it does nothing. But if `name` is specified and `attribute` is specified and different from `name`, then the form can be accessed using the value of either `name` or `attribute`.

Relevant section:

```
<!-- The "action" element describes an ActionMapping object that is to be used
    to process a request for a specific module-relative URI. The following
    attributes are defined:

    attribute       Name of the request-scope or session-scope attribute that
                    is used to access our ActionForm bean, if it is other than
                    the bean's specified "name". Optional if "name" is specified,
                    else not valid.
```